# Setting NAs with zeros in matrix with lapply seems does not work well?

Tags: r

I have these matrices.

```
matr <- list()

matr[[i]] <- c(0, NA, 3, 4, 4,
            0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 0, NA, 1,
            0, 0, NA, 0, 3,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
matr[[i]] <- matrix(matr[[i]], 5, 5)
```

I want to set NA to zero using the following code:

```
x <- lapply(matr,function(x) x[is.na(x) <- 0])
```

Then I got this result:

```
> x
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
numeric(0)

[[3]]
numeric(0)
```

Why it does not return the matrices? Is my code correct? any help please?

Comment: `matr[is.na(matr)] <- 0` should do it

Comment: With `lapply`, `lapply(matr,function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x})`.

Comment: The answer from @lmo works fine. This should be regarded as the first right answer.

Comment: Yes I aggree with you @LuísTelles.

Comment: @Imo, could you plesae set your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `lapply` works on lists and return lists I think that isn't what you want.
I think using `apply` here fits better.

Try `x <- apply(matr[[1]], 2, function(x){
       x[is.na(x)] <- 0
       x
})`

The number 2 here indicates that you want to operate column-wise instead of row-wise (1st margin are rows, and 2nd margin are columns).

Also notice that you had put the `<-` operator within the brackets which was a wrong sintax.

EDIT:

It seems that I have misunderstood your question.
Here follows a code that works for an entire list:

`lapply(matr, function(x){
  apply(x, 2, function(y){
    y[is.na(y)] <- 0
    y
  })
})`